# Reconnect Python Script for Netgear DGN2200v4

Tags: python, python-2.7

i need a script for my Netgear DGN2200v4 that let me change ip every x seconds. Searching online i find this code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import re
import urllib2
from base64 import b64encode
from time import sleep

BASE_URL = 'http://192.168.0.1/'
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'admin'

id_regex = re.compile('setup.cgi\?id=(\w+)"')

auth = "Basic %s" % b64encode("%s:%s" % (USERNAME, PASSWORD))

def load_html(url, data = None):
    request = urllib2.Request(BASE_URL + url, data,
                              {"Authorization": auth})
    result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    return result.read()

# Evito eccezione Unauthorized
try:
    load_html('')
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    pass

# Chiamo la schermata di riepilogo
html = load_html('setup.cgi?next_file=RST_st_poe.htm')
ID = id_regex.search(html).group(1)

# Lancio la disconnessione
load_html('setup.cgi?id=' + ID,
          'todo=disconnect&this_file=RST_st_poe.htm&next_file=RST_st_poe.htm&SID=')

# Attendo 3 secondi
sleep(3)

# Chiamo la schermata di riepilogo
html = load_html('setup.cgi?next_file=RST_st_poe.htm')
ID = id_regex.search(html).group(1)

# Lancio la riconnessione
load_html('setup.cgi?id=' + ID,
          'todo=connect&this_file=RST_st_poe.htm&next_file=RST_st_poe.htm&SID=')

# Attendo 7 secondi
sleep(7)

# Logout
load_html('setup.cgi?todo=logout')
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/stickell/9973973)

but it doesn't work on my pc.
I've chanded 'USERNAME' and 'PASSWORD' with my credential and setted PPPOE protocol and this is the log.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\Documents\dgnd3700.py", line 31, in <module>
    html = load_html('setup.cgi?next_file=RST_st_poe.htm')
  File "C:\Users\x\Documents\dgnd3700.py", line 19, in load_html
    result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

How can i solve? Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

From the traceback it looks as though the connection and authorisation is successful but the path specified in

```
html = load_html('setup.cgi?next_file=RST_st_poe.htm')
```

is incorrect, hence the 404 error.

Maybe install wireshark or fiddler, start a trace, then run through the steps manually (with a web browser) and see the path that is requested.  You can then modify the entry to the load_html function to reflect the correct path you find.